# OpenAL set Fixed volume

Tags: ios, iphone, sprite-kit, openal

i'm using OpenAL to play background music and sound effects in a game, the code to play background music is this;

```
- (void) playSoundBack
{


alGenSources(1, &sourceIDBack);

NSString *audioFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"music" ofType:@"wav"];
NSURL *audioFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:audioFilePath];

AudioFileID afid;
OSStatus openAudioFileResult = AudioFileOpenURL((__bridge CFURLRef)audioFileURL, kAudioFileReadPermission, 0, &afid);

if (0 != openAudioFileResult)
{
    NSLog(@"An error occurred when attempting to open the audio file %@: %ld", audioFilePath, openAudioFileResult);
    return;
}

UInt64 audioDataByteCount = 0;
UInt32 propertySize = sizeof(audioDataByteCount);
OSStatus getSizeResult = AudioFileGetProperty(afid, kAudioFilePropertyAudioDataByteCount, &propertySize, &audioDataByteCount);

if (0 != getSizeResult)
{
    NSLog(@"An error occurred when attempting to determine the size of audio file %@: %ld", audioFilePath, getSizeResult);
}

UInt32 bytesRead = (UInt32)audioDataByteCount;

void *audioData = malloc(bytesRead);

OSStatus readBytesResult = AudioFileReadBytes(afid, false, 0, &bytesRead, audioData);

if (0 != readBytesResult)
{
    NSLog(@"An error occurred when attempting to read data from audio file %@: %ld", audioFilePath, readBytesResult);
}

AudioFileClose(afid);

ALuint outputBuffer;
alGenBuffers(1, &outputBuffer);

alBufferData(outputBuffer, AL_FORMAT_STEREO16, audioData, bytesRead, 44100);

if (audioData)
{
    free(audioData);
    audioData = NULL;
}


alSourcef(sourceIDBack, AL_GAIN, 0.1f);

alSourcei(sourceIDBack, AL_BUFFER, outputBuffer);
alSourcei(sourceIDBack, AL_LOOPING, AL_TRUE);
alSourcePlay(sourceIDBack);
```

}

With another similar block of code i play some effects during the game. All the sound are played but i have a problem with volumes... The background music volume change and it seems not an absolute value... When the other effects are playing the background music volume is low as i have set in with AL_GAIN,but when no other effect is playing the background music sounds too loud (or at least this is my sensation...). Why the music has this behaviour? The volume setting like 0.1 are relative? It is possible to set a fixed and universal value?

Comment: First thing to check is whether the audio files sound correct when played back regularly on your computer, if not use Audacity to try and normalize volume levels. Note that sounds will sound differently (including volume) depending on content (some audio sounds louder even though technically it's the same volume/dba), device (vs computer speakers) and depending on whether you are listening to internal speakers or earplugs/headphones.

Comment: Thanks i have tried to normalize all the sounds, now all sounds louder but the problem still remains...When only the background music is played the "background music volume" is louder...